# WPF border for child grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, border

I am developing a WPF application. I have the following code for the XAML.

```
<Window Height="800" Width="800">

<Grid Height="800" Width="800">

<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
<Grid Height="150" Width="150">

<--elements -->

</Grid>
</Border>
<Grid Height="150" Width="150">
<--elements -->

</Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

My problem is when I'm trying to assign border to the child grids. I'm not able to see the border around the child grid. Any Ideas for getting the border around the child grids.
The above code give border to parent grid.

Solution: The default vertical alignment and horizontal alignment for border are stretch.
The following code works perfect.

```
<Grid Height="800" Width="800">

<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left"       VerticalAlignent="Top">
<Grid Height="150" Width="150">

<--elements -->

</Grid>
</Border>
<Grid Height="150" Width="150">
<--elements -->

</Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` to your Border like:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: The code above just added thickness and color to border.. your Child grid as the nature of grid will strech to fill parent grid hence it seems to you as if border is on parent